# How to fix an audio-set with wrong levels

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I have a set of 300 audios. I use those files in an App, as the voice of an animated character.

So, the thing is, that I can't find a process that take the audio, and "normalize" its levels to make a plain file. The thing is, I've used a software (Sample Manager for Mac) to Normalize the audios, but the result I'm getting is not the expected, at all.

As an example, I have this waveform:

[image: Waveform] [image]

As you may see, when the character gets "excited", the voice of the girl who made the audio raises a peak higher than the rest of the audio, and the same happens but with lower volumes. So, I need to stabilize the whole audio to a predefined level.

The thing is, the character moves his mouth based on the output volume.

Is a compressor what I need? A normalizer? What's the process to accomplish this?

Sorry if I've been inexact in terms, or if my explanation is not very clear, I have no idea about audio, I'm a programmer :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The thing is, the character moves his mouth based on the output volume.` Could you expand on how this relates to what you're trying to do with the audio?

Comment: Yes, I have a module that gives me the output volume during audio playback. It gives me a value from 0.0 to 1.0 (not really sure how many dBs 1.0 means). So, I define my min and max volume. Let's suppose, 0.5 is my minimum (mouth closed) and 0.8 is my maximum (mouth opened). If the audio volume is too high, the mouth is always opened, if it's too low, it never opens, and if it changes during the course of the playback, well, the result is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but here's what I think you need to do:

1. Add some compression.  This will bring down the peaks closer to the average level.  It will only affect the peaks, not the rest of the audio.
2. Normalize.  This will raise the level of the the *whole* audio clip to the specified level.

The end result will be less variation in volume (shorter peaks) and a more even volume across all the audio clips.

Comment: great, I started to post my answer before this post. Thank you! I'll add a normalization task too for all the clips.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it. What I needed was a Compressor finally.

Using Sample Manger with this parameters I achieved what I needed.

[image]